# pfSense dropping gateway interface randomly

Tags: pfsense

The basic topology of the office is

ISP-Router <-> pfSense <-> Switch <-> Servers and APs.

It has been newly deployed
Once a while our internet goes out and one of us has to manually get inside LAN and renew the gateway interface.

Our ISP gives us a fixed set of public ips.

(1) Does pfSense drop or try to reset the interface on its own or is it all on the ISP side?

(2) Once the WAN gateway is down on pfSense, is there any way remotely to restart/reset the gateway interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have fixed IPs, but mentioned renewing the WAN. I'm assuming it's DHCP, with your fixed IP assigned as a reservation.

Not enough info to offer any suggestions. What's the status of the interface before you renew it? What's in the system log when it's trying to renew its IP?

Likely either your connection briefly drops out and your modem assigns you a private IP that can't get anywhere, or your DHCP lease fails to renew for some reason.

Comment: Changed to static and not it's not having hiccups. Thanks.

Comment: Where you can set it as static, that's always preferable. Not because there's any problem inherent in doing DHCP generally speaking, but there are cases with some cable modems for instance in the "modem assigns you a private IP" scenario I mentioned where a static WAN might mask that kind of problem.